# Разница между begin и cbegin

Tags: c++

В чём разница между `begin` и `cbegin`, `end` и `cend` и т.д.?

Comment: А что имелось в виду под `и т.д.`?

Comment: @alexolut, вроде у `rbegin`/`rend` тоже пары с `c` есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy палка о двух концах :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Методы с префиксом `c` возвращают *константные итераторы*. Это означает, что

- Через них нельзя изменять значения.
- А ещё их можно использовать с константными объектами.

Answer (score 5):

До `c++11` в Стандарте языка не было функций-членов `cbegin`, `cend` для контейнерных классов. Были просто соответствующие перегрузки функций `begin`, `end`, которые возвращали `Containter::iterator` для неконстантных объектов и `Containter::const_iterator` для константных объектов.

С выходом Стандарта `c++11` ситуация изменилась. Т.е. если нам однозначно нужен *константный итератор* (независимо от константности контейнера) следует выбирать `cbegin`/`cend`. Если контантность итератора не важна - можно использовать `begin`/`end`, правильная перегрузка будет выбрана на основании наличия/отсутствия константности контейнера.

Необходимость добавления `cbegin`/`cend` была обусловлена в том числе и появлением возможности выводить тип переменной на основании типа правостороннего выражения:

```
auto it = c.begin(); // it будет типа const_iterator или iterator в зависимости от типа 'c'
auto it = c.cbegin(); // it всегда будет иметь тип const_iterator
```